# What exactly rotates along the lateral axis? Is 'rotate' mathematically correct?

Tags: terminology

Researching the etymology of 'rotate' (that [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/167704) lacks!), I chanced on [Anas Maaz](https://www.quora.com/profile/Anas-Maaz-1)'s [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-when-airplanes-take-off-the-pilot-says-rotate/answer/Anas-Maaz-1):

> What many does not know is 'rotate' is just not a fancy word, but it involves a real physical rotation. When Rotation speed (Vr) is reached, the pilot pulls the control column which deflects the horizontal stabilizer, causing **a rotation along the lateral axis of the airplane lifting up the nose wheel**.

1. Am I correct that Maaz's referring to the 'lateral axis' in the diagram beneath?

[image]

2. Even if yes, what exactly ROTATES? How does the lateral axis ROTATE?

Imagine the wing on the y-axis and time on the x-axis, like [the graph beneath](https://www.satcom.guru/2019/04/what-happened-on-et302.html). 
I don't think it's correct mathematically to state that an axis rotates, when it's the function that moves up as time passes?

[image]

Comment: An interesting mathematical subtlety is that in general, rotations occur *in a plane* as opposed to *about axis*. It just so happens that in 3D, a plane has an orthogonal axis. But there is not axis to a plane in 2D space, although you can rotate things to your heart's content. In 4D and higher, you get all kinds of weird.

Comment: Note that the quote in your question does not say the *axis* rotates, but that the plane rotates *along* the axis.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes that is the lateral axis of the aircraft.
2. The aeroplane rotates about the lateral axis, causing the nose to go up/down. The aeroplane then descends or climbs, causing the aeroplane axes to shift relative to earth axes. But the aeroplane axes are all defined relative to the aeroplane.

Comment: One tiny nitpick. Before liftoff the axis of rotation is actually the landing gear axles rather than the cog as it is in flight.

Answer (score 0):

1: Yes, rotation around the lateral axis will make the aircraft pitch. You understood that correct. On the other hand lateral rotation means something else, namely roll.

2: Its not the axis that rotates, its the aircraft that rotates. The axis is in a body fixed reference coordinate system, hence the whole coordinate system (and aircraft) rotates in relation to earth.